# Strategy for making computer art

Tags: java, c#, algorithm

This post might seem a bit strange. The thing is im experimenting with new things for my digital signage application. Im looking into making some kind of digital art (art as in paintings etc.). I am thinking on drawing some pixels in different colors on a bitmap or something (havent quite figured that one out yet). I imaging the work of art is being created in fromt of their eyes so each time you pas the screen you see some progress.

Does anyone have any tips, tricks approaches or anything else to point me in a direction. How about the algorithm, genertic seems to be a viable path to go down?

Comment: "I am thinking on drawing some pixels in different colors on a bitmap or something" well that is generally how images are done.

Comment: Math for the win.. dig into Fractals.. possibly the best thing for what you're planning.. lot's of games which have random maps use fractals.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal

Comment: So you guys are seriously voting down this question just because you didn't understand?

Comment: Even if the question is not very precise and has no definite answer I would love to see more approaches. Maybe make it a community wiki later. I voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really cool project I discovered recently that might help inspire some ideas.  It uses genetic programming to replicate another painting entirely out of geometrical shapes:   http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I meant with Fractals:

http://langexplr.blogspot.com/2007/06/creating-fractal-images-using-c-30.html

This is not Java tho, it's made in C#, but I'm sure you can do it in Java

Answer (score 0):

Winamp visualizations are a good source of dynamic generative art.
Possibly the best if someone is willing to devote some time to learn the program.
Even if this isn't the case they could be used for inspiration.